# Ruby On Rails: To Do App- Can't connect my form with to-do index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm trying to create a "to-do" app on Ruby on Rails that uses a simple "name" form to generate a to-do list.

I was successfully able to create the form as well as the main index page, but I am not able to connect the two. This means that I can type fill out the form but when I submit it, it just brings me back to the index page without the form item listed. I'm stumped!

Here are a view of my code:

welcome controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
   def index
       if user_signed_in?
          redirect_to :controller => "todoodoo" , :action => "index"
   end
end

   def home
      @todos = Todoodoo.where(done: false)
      @completes = Todoodoo.where(done: true)
   end
end
```

todo controller (todoodoo):

```
class TodoodooController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @todos = Todoodoo.where(done: false)
      @completes = Todoodoo.where(done: true)
   end

def new
   @todo = Todoodoo.new
end

def todo_params
   params.require(:todoodoo).permit(:name, :done)
end

def create
   @todo = Todoodoo.new(todo_params)

   if @todo.save
     redirect_to todoodoo_index_path, :notice => "Your To-Do item was created!"
   else
     render "new"
   end
 end

def update
   @todo = Todoodoo.find(todo_params[:id])

   if @todo.update_attribute(:done, true)
     redirect_to todoodoo_index_path, :notice => "Your To-Do item was marked as done!"
   else
     redirect_to todoodoo_index_path, :notice => "Your To-Do item was unable to be marked as done!"
   end
 end

def destroy
   @todo = Todoodoo.find(todo_params[:id])
   @todo.destroy

   redirect_to todoodoo_index_path, :notice => "Your To-Do item was deleted!"

   end
end
```

This is my view file for the todo controller (todoodooo):

```
<h1> To-Do </h1>


<h2> To Do </h2>
  <% @todos.each do |t| %>
    <p>
      <strong><%= t.name %></strong>
      <small><%= link_to "Mark as Done", todoodoo_path(t), :method => :put %></small>
    </p>
<% end %>

<h2> Completed </h2>
  <% @completes.each do |t| %>
    <p>
      <%= t.name %>
      <small><%= link_to "Remove", t, :confirm => "Is it okay to remove this from the list?", :method => :delete %></small>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This is my view file for the form:

```
<h1> Add new item to your To-Do list </h1>
  <%= form_for @todo, :url => todoodoo_index_path(@todo) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :Name %>: <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :done, :value => false %>
  <%= f.submit "Add to To-Do list", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

And my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   get 'welcome/home'

   get 'todoodoo/index'
   match "todoodoo/index" => "todoodoo#index", :via => :post


   get 'people/new'

   devise_for :users

   root 'welcome#home'

   resources :todoodoo do
     member do
     put :complete
   end
end
```

I'm really new to Rails development so I apologize if I missed something out or if this doesn't make sense. I've tried my best to include every dependent file. Thanks for any input you can add. Thanks! (also, forgive me of the formatting, please know that there isn't any errors in the formatting in my code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're new, here's what you need to do

By the way, I'd *highly* recommend [upgrading to Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails). If you're learning the system, there's no point using legacy code to do it!

--

```
#Gemfile
gem 'rails', '4.1.5' 

#config/routes.rb
root to: "todoodoos#index"
resources :todoodoo

#app/controllers/todoodoo_controller.rb
Class TodoodooController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @todoodoos = Tododoo.all
   end

   def new
      @todoodoo = Todoodoo.new
   end

   def create
      @todoodoo = Todoodoo.new(todo_params)
      @todoodoo.save
   end

   private

   def todo_params
      params.require(:todoodoo).permit(:name)
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to add the following views:

```
#app/views/todoodoo/index.html.erb
<% @todoodoo.all.each do |todo| %>
   <%= link_to todo.name, todo %> #-> goes to show action
<% end %>

#app/views/todoodoo/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @todoodoo do |f| %> #-> goes to create action
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/views/todoodoo/create.html.erb
Succesfully created!!
```

---

I can explain *how* this works if you try it & find that it does work

Your current setup is so conflicting that I felt it best to provide you with the required code you need!

Comment: Really appreciate your code, Rich! It's working well. And the code makes sense. Thanks for simplifying the code!

Comment: Hi Rich. It seems like i'm running into an issue with the params function (todo_params)

I get this error in my console: "param is missing or the value is empty" Can you help me understand why this doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks Paul - do you know which `param` is missing or empty?

Comment: I'm not sure which 'param' is missing, but this information can help: in the code section 'params.require(:todoodoo).permit(:name)' what does '(:todoodoo)' point to?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your form simple by removing the :url. Right now your form is confused between to doing the New action and the Index action of your to do list.

```
<h1> Add new item to your To-Do list </h1>
  <%= form_for @todo do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :Name %>: <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :done, :value => false %>
  <%= f.submit "Add to To-Do list", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```